# Compare two columns and return the result in a thrid

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have this table :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | allowed_to_play_pokemon_go_after | last_played_pokemon_go |  name |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |                        20-JUL-16 |              19-JUL-16 |  Jhon |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  |                        19-JUL-16 |              21-JUL-16 |  Bill |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to make a select like that :

```
SELECT name, (last_played_pokemon_go > allowed_to_play_pokemon_go_after) as must_punish
FROM myTable;
```

Where 'must_punish' has to bo a boolean (1/0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
SELECT name,
       (case when last_played_pokemon_go > allowed_to_play_pokemon_go_after then 1 else 0
        end) as must_punish
FROM myTable;
```

Oracle (the database) doesn't have a boolean data type.  A number should be fine.

Comment: Thanks ! Just what I was looking for : )